# Creating dockerized Postgresql with initial scripts

Tags: postgresql, docker

I have a yml file that

```
  2 volumes:¬                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
  6     quartz-pg-master_data:¬                                                                                             
  7 ¬                                                                                                                       
  8 networks:¬                                                                                                              
  9     hostnet:¬                                                                                                           
 10         external: true¬                                                                                                 
 11         name: host¬

 21 configs:¬                                                                                                                                                                        
 24     quartz-create_quartz_tables-20201019-1.sh:¬                                                                         
 25         file: ./config/quartz/create.sql¬ 

 15     quartz-pg-master:¬                                                                                                  
 14         image: postgres¬                                                                                                
 13         networks:¬                                                                                                      
 12             - internal¬                                                                                                 
 11         ports:¬                                                                                                         
 10             - published: 5432¬                                                                                          
  9               target: 5432¬                                                                                             
  8               mode: host¬                                                                                               
  7         environment:¬                                                                                                   
  6             PGDATA: /pg_data¬                                                                                           
  5             POSTGRES_DB: "quartz"
                POSTGRES_USER: "quartz"
                POSTGRES_PASSWORD: "password"¬                                                                                      
  4         configs:¬                                                                                                       
  3             - source: quartz-create_quartz_tables-20201019-1.sh¬                                                        
  2               target: /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/create.sql¬                                                           
  1         volumes:¬                                                                                                       
  0             - quartz-pg-master_data:/pg_data¬
```

which has create.sql:

```
CREATE TABLE qrtz_service_job_details
  (
    SCHED_NAME VARCHAR(120) NOT NULL,
    JOB_NAME  VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL,
    JOB_GROUP VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL,
    DESCRIPTION VARCHAR(250) NULL,
    JOB_CLASS_NAME   VARCHAR(250) NOT NULL, 
    IS_DURABLE BOOL NOT NULL,
    IS_NONCONCURRENT BOOL NOT NULL,
    IS_UPDATE_DATA BOOL NOT NULL,
    REQUESTS_RECOVERY BOOL NOT NULL,
    JOB_DATA BYTEA NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (SCHED_NAME,JOB_NAME,JOB_GROUP)
);

CREATE TABLE qrtz_service_triggers
  (
    SCHED_NAME VARCHAR(120) NOT NULL,
    TRIGGER_NAME VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL,
    TRIGGER_GROUP VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL,
    JOB_NAME  VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL, 
    JOB_GROUP VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL,
    DESCRIPTION VARCHAR(250) NULL,
    NEXT_FIRE_TIME BIGINT NULL,
    PREV_FIRE_TIME BIGINT NULL,
    PRIORITY INTEGER NULL,
    TRIGGER_STATE VARCHAR(16) NOT NULL,
    TRIGGER_TYPE VARCHAR(8) NOT NULL,
    START_TIME BIGINT NOT NULL,
    END_TIME BIGINT NULL,
    CALENDAR_NAME VARCHAR(200) NULL,
    MISFIRE_INSTR SMALLINT NULL,
    JOB_DATA BYTEA NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (SCHED_NAME,TRIGGER_NAME,TRIGGER_GROUP),
    FOREIGN KEY (SCHED_NAME,JOB_NAME,JOB_GROUP) 
    REFERENCES qrtz_service_JOB_DETAILS(SCHED_NAME,JOB_NAME,JOB_GROUP) 
);

...
```

for quartz init.db.

I am successfully initializg postresql with logs:

[image]

When I am running

docker exec -ti  bash, then

su quartz

and my result is:

root@3fac28fb199d:/# su quartz
su: user quartz does not exist.

However, I have tried with postgres -> su postgres

I can successfully go in but after that when I run psql it gives me this error

```
postgres@3fac28fb199d:/$ psql
psql: error: could not connect to server: FATAL:  role "postgres" does not exist
```

Seems like my db and users are not created at all. What could be the problem?

Comment: Can you edit the question to replace the YAML file with syntactically valid YAML, and the log file with the actual logs and not an image?  PostgreSQL and its surrounding Linux environment have separate user spaces and so I wouldn't expect to be able to `su` to a PostgreSQL-specific user (in Docker I wouldn't expect to `su` at all); have you tried supplying the credentials from the YAML file as command-line options to `psql`?

Comment: Yeah sorry for the bad post, I have just solved the problem, posting as an answer. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

In the docker bash container I need to use

psql dbname username so in my case it worked and my tables were created.

psql quartz quartz